# Compressor is intermittently turning off

Tags: electrical, hvac

I have a 16 SEER Carrier and when it works it's fabulous. Probably 8 years old. But some days it will just suddenly turn off. The Nest Thermostat keeps going, thinking it's asking for cooling, and the fan runs, but no cool air of course.

I thought it might be the Nest because it's literally like version 1, so I thought about replacing it but then I realized, I have 3 Nests because the system is zoned. So now I think it's probably the Honeywell Zone Controller. So I was thinking about just getting that removed. It's really hard to find anyone who wants to repair anything especially things that have to be diagnosed. I may just replace the whole system.

**Update**: for sure is not the utility, emailed them and they responded.

Guy came out and said the motor on the fan is shot. It spins, but slowly. Problem is compressor is hard to get at so replacing it will be a hassle. Moving the compressor out from under the deck not a great idea because it's 9 years old so probably going to do a new unit.

Very strange that it will turn on and run sometimes just for minutes. Of course earlier in the day it runs longer so probably is just overheating.

Answer (score 2):

You don't happen to have a load management ("demand response") device from the electric utility installed on that air conditioner, do you? These devices allow the utility to turn off air conditioner compressors for a period of time while the indoor fan continues to run. Likewise, check whether your Nest thermostats are configured for such a feature. Though I haven't used one, search results suggest they have this capability.

Throwing parts at the problem is certainly an option, but doing just a little more diagnosis from where you're at now will not be difficult.

One of the first things to figure out is whether the call for cool is propagating through the zone controller and out to the compressor's contactor (relay). That's easy enough to do. The zone controller might just have an LED on it to indicate what it's doing and why. If not, or if you don't want to rely on the indicator, a few seconds with a volt meter will confirm.

There should be small-gauge cable, probably 18 gauge with two conductors, going from the zone controller to the compressor. Find that and use a volt meter set for AC volts (200 volt range, if it isn't auto-ranging) and measure the voltage between those two conductors. It should show approximately 0 volts when there's no call for cooling and approximately 24 volts (plus or minus several volts) when the compressor is running.

Get some baseline observation during a period when the compressor is working properly, then go measure again during a period when it's not working. The results should help you determine whether the problem is in the zone controller, thermostats, or in the compressor unit itself.

Comment: Wish you were in Los Angeles, yeah I watched a few videos about zone controllers, I know where mine is, I will go look at it. The Compressor JUST turned off.

Yes I DO have a tied system and the utility can turn off my stuff however when they have up until now it has shown that on the display? maybe I should call and ask them. And tell them that if it turns out they were doing it and I replace the system I will sue them.

Comment: @Rob you would sue the power company for turning off some of your power in cases where there is not enough power?

Comment: @user253751 it's the American way... :(

Comment: since it usually appears on the display and it's not appearing on the display it's probably not what is happening.

Comment: They weren't doing it, they wrote me back.

Comment: @FreeMan as a fellow coder: your snark didn't parse for me.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a SWAG that is what I would expect and say the compressor is cycling down because of high head pressure. This happens when there is not enough cooling, in your case the fan motor running slow. Not knowing the unit I cannot be sure this will work but for a test place a large window fan so it moves air through the condenser in the same direction that the fan does. This should extend the run time by a noticeable amount. If so replace the fan that is the most economical solution. You could just replace the fan motor, that will cost more then the fan test but will probably fix it as the fan test will show. I did this last year on a commercial 30 Ton sub zero system, ran it that way for two weeks before we got a new fan motor. The fans were plugged in and left running.